# Passing inherited class to function in c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions

I'm having a little problem with inheritance in C++ that I can't quite figure out.

So, say I have some classes derived from stl list, i.e:

```
class Class1: public list<T>{
      virtual func1();

}

class Class2 : public Class1<w/e>{
         func1();
}
```

The problem I'm having is when passing these to a function. How can I properly pass an instance of one of these to a function so that it will use the proper virtual function if it is possible for an instance of either type to be passed? I haven't done inheritance and virtual functions in awhile so I am a bit rusty here.
(This assuming that the function is not a member function of the classes).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to pass them to the function as a reference

```
int function(Class1& obj);
```

or as a pointer;

```
int function(Class1* obj);
```

and it should just plain call the correct version of the virtual method.

If you pass them without either of those

```
int function(Class1 obj);
```

The object will be copy constructed to always be a Class1 in the function, and will always call Class1::func1()

Comment: So in the function call I assume it is the base class and at runtime it will decide which it actually is?

Comment: Exactly, since both classes are at least a Class1, that will allow either to be passed in and it decides runtime which virtual method to call.

Comment: It always is the base class. Every instance of a class **is** an instance of every class from which it was derived. The purpose of virtual functions is to allow code to call a function on an instance of a base class and invoke the correct version of that function.